# Dell M4500 does not connect to internet

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, dell-precision

I have a Dell M4500 that does not connect to the internet. I have called Dell and they have replaced the motherboard but it does not work. They told me that it is a software problem. It suddenly stopped working, both the cable and wireless card.

The SIM card work and I can connect to internet with that. The LAN card is active but the computer symbol in the right bottom corner is having the read cross over it. When I try `ipconfig` the only card that is listed is the SIM and bluetooth. There must be another solutiuon to this than reinstalling.

How can I fix this without reinstalling Win 7? It is like the PC does not recognize the cards anymore...

Comment: Did you check device manager to see if the drivers have any errors/updates?

Comment: Yes, no errors.

Comment: What does the network troubleshooter say?

Comment: I assume you are using windows?

Comment: Yes, it is Windows 7. The troubleshooter says that it can't fix it.

Comment: IPV4 and IPV6 not connected is what it says in the status dialog.

Answer (score 0):

first of all, try reinstalling the wireless driver. You can get it from [here](http://www.dell.com/support/drivers/us/en/ussoho1/DriversHome/NeedProductSelection).

If that fixes it, then great.

If not, try downloading a linux live disk (any of Ubuntu, LinuxMint, Knoppix etc) and boot into a live linux session (just put the cd in your drive and restart your pc). Once in the linux session, if you can connect/see wireless networks you know that it is not a hardware problem and you should be able to find a software solution in windows.

On my m4500, LinuxMint detects the wireless card automatically so if it does not in your case it probably means you have a hardware problem and you need to lean on Dell.